# Scrapy CSV header row format with Multiple spiders and CSVItemExporter

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am running four spiders and exporting the data into one csv file. However, when the second spider runs  it and gets data it creates the same row with column names. I tried to format the row header with FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS but that did not work.

What I am looking to do is have 1 row header and populate all the data below it for each spider. The image shows the error and below I gave an example of what I am looking to accomplish.

I did look at CsvItemExporter but am not clear how I would get the data from all four spiders and export the data. I have read over the documentation but still don't see how I would tie all this together.

```
TMP_FILE = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.modules['products'].__file__), 'tmp/allproducts.csv')
FIELDS = ['url', 'company', 'location', 'price', 'make', 'model', 'year', 'height']

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
    'FEED_URI': TMP_FILE,
    'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS': FIELDS,
})
process.crawl(Spider1)
process.crawl(Spider2)
process.start()
```

[image]

Comment: You can not do that directly. Since each scrapy spider is a separate process. What you can possible do is, write individual file and merge it together.

Comment: is there a way to create 4 different spreed sheets using crawler process? Was thinking I can pass the data from each spider it to an items pipeline and export to one csv file. Do you know if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Each spider write on its own file, and then you combine everything as the end in a separate process.
2. Instead of writing into a file, the spiders have an item pipeline that writes into a messaging queue, and a separate process consumes the messages from the queue and write into a single CSV file.

Comment: I am working on the first one using pandas to combine the sheets into one. I am curious to know how to perform the final step in the second recommendation you made. Can you please point in a direction where I can learn more about this.